# Receiving BroadcastReceiver continually

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My broadcast receivers are invoking continually

```
<receiver android:name=".RebootBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectionInternetBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Please help, tried to find on google but couldn't find. `onReceive` is being called by many times.

Comment: Which smartphone? Maybe is your phone, not your code.

Comment: Samsung s5 with Android 6, this is random issue, not every time.

Comment: Test it in another device. I had this random issue with a Samsung device too.